# Programação C - Trocar elementos da matriz

Tags: c, matriz

O meu código abaixo deverá trocar os elementos da matriz, se for 1 trocará por 0 e se for 0 trocará por 1. Porém a matriz impressa está com todos os elementos 0:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
//entrada: m n (matriz com m linhas e n colunas)
//         ex.: 3 4
//              0 1 1 0
//              1 0 1 0
//              0 1 0 1. Digitar em sequencia
//saída: 1 0 0 1
//       0 1 0 1
//       1 0 1 0. Trocar os valores.
int main(){
    int matriz[3][4];
    int i, j;
    //digitar/ler valores da matriz
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++){
        scanf("%d", &matriz[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    //trocar/ler os valores da matriz
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            if (matriz[i][j] == 0){
                matriz[i][j] = 1;
            }
            if(matriz[i][j] == 1){
                matriz[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    //escrever a nova matriz com valores trocados
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++){
        printf("%d ", matriz[i][j]);
        }
    printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

O problema está aqui:

```
            if (matriz[i][j] == 0){
                matriz[i][j] = 1;
            }
            if(matriz[i][j] == 1){
                matriz[i][j] = 0;
            }
```

O primeiro `if` entra quando é zero, e ele muda para um. Isso faz com que o segundo `if` também entre, e portanto, ele volta para zero.

A solução é usar o `else`:

```
            if (matriz[i][j] == 0){
                matriz[i][j] = 1;
            } else {
                matriz[i][j] = 0;
            }
```

Ou melhor ainda, dá para eliminar o `if` completamente:

```
            matriz[i][j] = !matriz[i][j];
```